# Mongo DB query - Transform unix date from document in Date Object to compare

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I want make a query to return all documents from a collection created in that day.
This is what i done so far:

```
db.entities.find({"creDate":{"$gte": new Date(Date.now() - (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24))}});
```

The problem is that the atributte "creDate" format is unix. Example: 1653408094.1847994

So, in the above query i need to convert "creDate" to Date Object.
Thanks!

Comment: What about `db.entities.find({"creDate":{"$gte": (Date.now() - (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24))}}); `?

Comment: Just enter unix instead of creating a date in the query

Comment: @nimrodserok thanks for help but this: `db.entities.find({"creDate":{"$gte": (Date.now() - (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24))}});`  doesn´t work ... 
I need to convert this: new Date(Date.now() - (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) to something like this: 1653436800

Comment: Thanks for your Help, I reached the solution! 
`db.entities.find({"creDate":{"$gte": new Date(Date.UTC(new Date().getFullYear(), new Date().getMonth(), new Date().getDate(),0,0,0)).getTime()/1000}}); `